# it is possible to map the local storage of an usb modem (globe tattoo)?

Tags: vb.net, at-command, dongle

I'm working a send/receive sms using a dongle (globe tattoo).

But I'm having trouble on retrieving the sms from the local storage not on the sim. Using this command: `AT+CPMS=ME` I get an OK result but no list of sms from the local storage.

Is it possible to map the local storage of an usb modem (globe tattoo)?

Answer (score 0):

This should absolutely be possible (as long as `ME` is listed as supported by `AT+CPMS=?`). According to [the specification](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/27005.htm), the syntax for the command is

```
+CPMS=<mem1>[,<mem2>[,<mem3>]]
```

where just specifying mem1 is fine. However in practice you should always specify both mem1 and mem2 since some phones might not like a split storage location for read/write (and I think some phones will return ERROR for this). So try runnig `AT+CPMS="ME","ME"` (notice the string quotes, if your modem returns OK for `AT+CPMS=ME` it is in violation of correct syntax as defined by [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en)).